# Possible to add a new line with spacing? Without using optional arg

Tags: tex-core, latex-base

Right now every time I make a new line, I am adding `\\[8pt]`.

Is there a way to automatically have text in a new line with spacing, without needing to specify the `[8pt]`?

Comment: Is making the document line spacing 8pt *everywhere* an option?  Or only in selected areas where you call upon \\?

Comment: Within lines of normal paragraphs, between paragraphs, between table rows or where? Except in tables, rarely you should use  \\ , and in tables, rarely you should use `\\[xx pt]`.  Add to the question a **compilable** document (not a chunk of code of the document) but as **mimimal** as possible and of course, showing this  problem, and only this problem, i.e., What here we called a a minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: it is rather rare to need to use a forced line break at all, so it is very weird to have lots of `\\[8pt]` but assuming you are using the default font size of 10pt on 12pt baseline then `\setlength\baselineskip{20pt}` would have increase all the baseline spacing by 8pt.